# The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed error

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to build my angular2 app using ng build but I am getting below error:-

```
The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed. Error: TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
Error: The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed. Error: TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Official\UI\angular3\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js:14:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Official\UI\angular3\node_modules\@angular\cli\tasks\eject.js:10:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

I even tried to delete existing node_modules and install again but it didn't work.

Any idea? Here is my package.json:-

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.6",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.6",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.6",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.6",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "angular": "^1.6.4",
    "angular2": "^2.0.0-beta.21",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.15",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "^0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.0.17",
    "ng2-translate": "2.4.1",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.3.2",
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
```

Comment: My case updated my [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli), http://itechiesol.blogspot.in/2017/07/angular-compiler-cli-package-was-not.html

Comment: I tried this but still same error.

Comment: did you execute this command `npm install` ?

Comment: Yes.. I tried... Now after changing dependencies version to    **@angular/common": "4.3.2"** I am getting  **Cannot read property 'config' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of null**

Answer (score 2):

You can uninstall, clean cache and update the latest version of Angular

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Read [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4391) for more information